# Diagnosing an intermittent system crash - how to analyse a spindump file

Tags: crash, logs, macos

I am trying to figure out the root cause of full system crashes that I am sometimes experiencing in MacOS. It's an ongoing but intermittent issue that I've been encountering both in  10.15 and also in 10.14 as well. I have a spindump file for the last time this happened, however, I really don't know how to interpret it at all so I'm not sure if this actually has any useful information to help me try to uncover the source of the problem.

Here is a basic overview of the context of when I'm experiencing the intermittent crashes. I am using some `node` based build tools for web development, this requires `node` and `npm` to install various node modules. From time to time I either install these fresh or run `npm update` on an existing installation to update the node modules. However, intermittently when I run `npm update` or `npm install` it will go so far and then I can see that the terminal has stopped responding, and then over a few minutes my whole system will gradually freeze up and become unresponsive, some apps may still be accessible for a short while but eventually it all freezes up and then the computer just reboots automatically.

So, a bit of a strange one, definitely weird to feel the computer getting overwhelmed by something that drastically! The one clue that feels like it may be relevant is that often the terminal seems to freeze at the point of installing / updating a node module called `fsevents`, and it's from this point on that the system freeze begins. Fsevents is a module that ties in natively to MaxOS' fsevents API which is used to get notifications about filesystem changes. Given that this issue seems to be related to updating files on my filesystem these seemed significant to me.

Leading on to my main question, how to usefully analyse a spindump file. In the .spin file I can see there is a reference to `npm`:

> Process:          node [80747] UUID:
>   8DC58230-C7B9-321B-9231-CA151134DC7C Path:
>   /usr/local/bin/node Architecture:     x86_64 Footprint:        273.55
>   MB Start time:       2020-04-09 17:05:28 +0100 End time:
>   2020-04-09 17:05:34 +0100 Num samples:      12 (1-12)
>
> Thread 0x6f4c20    Thread name "npm"    12 samples (1-12)    priority
>   24 (base 31)

and then several references to `FSevents`. I'm just unaware if any of this is actually giving a clue about the reason for the crash or is it just general information about what commands were run at the time the spindump was triggered, what processes were running at the time etc.

Thanks!